# How to add more gridlines in google chart?

Tags: html, google-api

I tried using
 hAxis: {count: 12},

but it ignores my count of 12 and just gives me 4 gridlines. Anyone has any idea how to add more gridlines? here is my code:

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          hAxis: {count: 12},
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: As you can see, I am getting 4 hAxis but I want 12, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this (Ref : [Google Line Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)).

1. By setting `vAxis.gridlines.count` to number of rows. This is better way to achieve this as this will automatically adjust with maximum value in chart. Check example below:

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          vAxis: {
            gridlines : {
              count : 12
            }
          },
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

2. By setting `vAxis.ticks` providing an array of values to be shown in chart. This is preferred only when chart will be static. Check example below:

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          vAxis: {
            ticks: [0, 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1200]
          },
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: You're a genius dude! I added the ticks method and it worked flawlessly! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I tried your first method too, and turns out the first method is indeed better if the chart is dynamic, which mine is so thanks yet again!

Comment: Hey Yogesh, those are 14 lines though. Or do you only count the lines with data in them?